# How to access an account if node is down

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, nodes, private-key, keystore

Consider a following scenario for a multi node private blockchain network:

If one node is down, how can I access accounts created on that node from another node without having private key of the account?

OR

If one node is down, how can I access accounts created on that node from another node as the private keys are residing on the node which is down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually answered the question yourself. **In order to act on behalf of an account, you need its private key**. As such, if the node is down it is impossible to retrieve any accounts associated with it through other nodes.

That would defeat the purpose of having a blockchain as a blockchain network consists of peers whose owners you do not necessarily trust, let alone entrust with the private key(s) to your account(s).